# How to extract the mx records from dig query using sed, awk or both tools

Tags: bash, awk, sed

here is the dig query result

```
$ dig gmail.com mx 

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.14-Ubuntu <<>> gmail.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60118
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri May 26 14:20:53 NPT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 161
```

i want to extract the `;;ANSWER SECTION:` part ..here its
;; ANSWER SECTION:

```
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

although the dig provided exact answer with just `dig gmail.com mx +short` 
im curious if theres way by using awk, sed or combining both

Comment: yes i did try .. dig gmail.com mx | awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n";  } { print $NF ; } ...  im working around this. i wouldnt have asked here if i knew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `Awk` statement as below,

```
dig gmail.com mx | awk '$0==";; ANSWER SECTION:"{f=1; next}!NF{f=0;}f'
```

to get the output as you need.

```
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      1484    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

The idea is to match the line containing your pattern `;; ANSWER SECTION:` set a flag on its occurrence and reset  it at the *next* occurring empty field.

Comment: Great answer.  Probably you could highlight the significance of the flag `f` at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
dig gmail.com mx | sed '/;; ANSWER SECTION:/,/^$/!d;//d;'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# dig gmail.com mx | awk '/;; ANSWER SECTION:/{p=1}!$0{p=0}p' | grep -v ANSWER
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```